# Android android.view.windowmanager$badtokenexception progressdialog

Tags: android

I try to use progressDialog in `Button` click ,but I have android.view.windowmanager$badtokenexception error. This is my code:

```
starus_fail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please Wait... ", "Loading... ");
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    somefunction();
                    if (dialog != null) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }

            }, 1000);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Instead of getApplicationContext pass YourActivity.this

Comment: Great it did. I hv posted it as an answer do upvote n accept it. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to have an answer for the above, ProgressDialog uses a context of the Activity calling it.

So just pass

```
 YourActivity.this
```

Instead of

```
getApplicationContext
```

See www.doubleencore.in/2013/06/context/
for more detailed understanding of contextual

Answer (score 1):

Do not use application context for create dialog. Instead use Activity context. Here you can get it from View.getContext(). so  replace your create of PorgressDialog to this:

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(arg0.getContext(), "Please Wait... ", "Loading... ");
```